# Chrome Inspect - close preview frame

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

In a recent update of Chrome, the "Inspect" window (`chrome://inspect/`) has a preview window (which shows the web page in an on-screen mobile frame).

How do I close it? The closest thing I have managed so far is to reduce the width so it does not take up as much screen real-estate.

Image example:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can toggle the screencast using the button highlighted below:

[image: Screenshot of <code>Toggle Screencast</code> button]